# Issue with my nested select statement on Athena (Column cannot be resolved)

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm writing a fairly simple nested select query to change the value in one of my columns but for some reason I keep getting an error related to the resolution of the columns: "Column 'test1' cannot be resolved"

As per the findings this question: [Amazon Athena - Column cannot be resolved on basic SQL WHERE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974089/amazon-athena-column-cannot-be-resolved-on-basic-sql-where-query)
I've tried to delete the column and re-add it with no luck.

Additionally, when I execute the below it works.

```
select
test1, test2, test3
from datanewdb;
```

Here is the code that isn't working:

```
select 
test1, test2, test3
from (
  select
  'FILLER',
  test2,
  test3
  from datanewdb)
datanewdb 
where test1 = '123';
```

The actual value of those columns on the table:

- test1: CODE 250
- test2: 12.50
- test3: negative

I would expect my code to return:

- test1: FILLER
- test2: 12.50
- test3: negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a sub-query in SQL only the columns defined in the `SELECT` clause are exposed outside of the sub-query.  If you want to be able to reference the column associated with the new literal value `'FILLER'`, you need to name it:

```sql
select test1, test2, test3
from (
    select
        'FILLER' AS test1,
        test2,
        test3
    from datanewdb
) datanewdb 
where test1 = '123';
```

Comment: Wow.. I was looking at the code for quite a bit of time, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you! I'm facing another issue now but it's unrelated to this question.